# Execute the Snowflake SQLs from a file and store output in different CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-connector

Thanks in advance. I am very new to Python & Python snowflake connector and need help to understand how it can be done.

Scenario: I have list of SQLS that i have put in a text file. Ex.. 5 SQL queries. I want to execute one by one in the Snowflake and store result of each SQL in a different Outputfile.

Please let me know your ideas and thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, and what's gone wrong? We can start with that

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CLI SnowSQL for this.

This is your SQL file **my_example.sql** you need to run

```
> cat my_example.sql
select current_database() as database, 
    current_timestamp() as timestamp, 
    current_warehouse() as warehouse;
```

Configure SnowSQL to connect to your account. You can refer [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config.html) to do it.

```
> snowsql
* SnowSQL * v1.2.21
Type SQL statements or !help
USER1#COMPUTE_WH@SF_DEMO_DB.SF_DEMO_SCHEMA>

USER1#COMPUTE_WH@SF_DEMO_DB.SF_DEMO_SCHEMA>!set output_format=csv

USER1#COMPUTE_WH@SF_DEMO_DB.SF_DEMO_SCHEMA>!spool my_example.log

USER1#COMPUTE_WH@SF_DEMO_DB.SF_DEMO_SCHEMA>!source my_example.sql
"DATABASE","TIMESTAMP","WAREHOUSE"
"SF_DEMO_DB","2022-08-10 03:37:12.236 -0700","COMPUTE_WH"
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.116s

USER1#COMPUTE_WH@SF_DEMO_DB.SF_DEMO_SCHEMA>!spool off

USER1#COMPUTE_WH@SF_DEMO_DB.SF_DEMO_SCHEMA>!exit
Goodbye!
```

The spool file **my_example.log** is the CSV output of your SQL file **my_example.sql**

```
> cat my_example.log
"DATABASE","TIMESTAMP","WAREHOUSE"
"SF_DEMO_DB","2022-08-10 03:37:12.236 -0700","COMPUTE_WH"
```